# Sparkle Framework problem (not displaying right version)

Tags: cocoa, macos, sparkle

I am using sparkle framework for the first time. I am trying to test it out and everything works perfectly, except it doesn't display the update version correctly. So for example this is my xml file on server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <rss version="2.0" xmlns:sparkle="http://www.andymatuschak.org/xml-namespaces/sparkle" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"> <channel>
      <title>Your Great App's Changelog</title>
      <link>http://localhost/test/SampleAppcast.xml</link>
      <description>Most recent changes with links to updates.</description>
      <language>en</language>


         <item>
            <title>Version 1.5 (2 bugs fixed; 3 new features)</title>
                        <sparkle:releaseNotesLink>
                            http://localhost/test/notes.html
                        </sparkle:releaseNotesLink>
            <pubDate>Wed, 15 Mar 2011 19:20:11 +0000</pubDate>
            <enclosure url="http://localhost/test/seglab.zip" sparkle:version="2.0" length="1623481" type="application/octet-stream" sparkle:dsaSignature="MCwCFD8H0l7NOhl7OXeqVM1+CeonHuKtAhRQXdB4alDeMPgSUaHhuX1Zx5GwTg==" />
         </item>

   </channel> </rss>
```

notice in the title tag, the name of the version is 1.5, but when I get a prompt for sparkle update, it says "App Name version 2.0 is now available - you have 1.0...."
It should say 1.5...
Why is this happening?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"It should say 1.5"* as in, *"App Name version **1.5** is now available - you have 1.0...."?*

Then you probably need to change this tag:

```
<enclosure
    url="http://localhost/test/seglab.zip"
    sparkle:version="2.0"
    length="1623481"
    ... />
```

to this:

```
<enclosure
    url="http://localhost/test/seglab.zip"
    sparkle:version="1.5"
    length="1623481"
    ... />
```

***Full disclosure: I have never used Sparkle before.*** This is just a guess based on eyeballing the XML.